# No Java virtual machine was found (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse

When trying to run Eclipse Kepler (for the first time), I get the following error:

[image]

I am aware that this issue has been solved many times before. However, I have changed eclipse.ini to say `-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\javaw.exe` but to no avail. The same error always comes up.

===UPDATE===
I added a line break after `-vm` and now I get this dialog box:
[image]

and the eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Do you escape the " " character?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you are trying to start a 64 bit version of Eclipse with a 32 bit version of Java. The bitness should match. You can download 64 bit Java [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Start Eclipse with a 64 bit JVM and the problem will go away.

To do so:

```
eclipse.exe -vm c:\path\to\64\bit\bin\javaw.exe
```

You can also update the the first two lines in your `eclipse.ini` file to use the 64 bit java by default by doing the following:

```
-vm
c:\path\to\64\bit\bin\javaw.exe
```

*(**NOTE**: be sure the argument and value each exist on a separate line)*

Also, you can also download a 32 bit version of Eclipse for use with 32 bit Java. The key is that the bitness is the same.

Comment: 64-bit java did not help.

Comment: Once have the same bitness it will work. Can you verify that you using both 64 bit java? The error in the your description indicates 64 bit eclipse with 32 bit java which cant work. If u get that 'exact'  same error, then you definitely have a mismatch. If you get something different i'll be happy to have a look.

Comment: I've reinstalled Java and deleted and downloaded Eclipse again. I made sure everything was 64 bit and that there were no previous versions already on my computer. Now I'm back to the original error message.

Comment: In your current error message, are you still seeing the following Java path: -vm
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\javaw.exe`? You will need to be sure the -vm option or eclipse.ini points to a valid 64 bit javaw.exe. You can test its validity by running /path/to/java.exe -version and verifying it is indeed 64 bit. Then ensure that java is used with eclipse.

Comment: No, it is `C:\Users\[USER]\Desktop\Java\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: OK, cool, since you have placed java within the eclipse install dir, you do not need to specify -vm in eclipse.ini or via -vm on the command line

Comment: Oh, one more thing to note. When using eclipse.ini, you must put -vm and /path/to.javaw.exe on separate lines. (That's bitten me before)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47603/discussion-between-cmd-and-insederec)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a note about the line break when using eclipse.ini. Definitely a 'gotcha' worth noting. I'm glad its finally working for you :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are pointing your 64-bit Eclipse at a 32-bit Java installation.  They need to match.  You can either get and use the equivalent 32-bit Eclipse download or make sure you install a 64-bit Java.

Comment: I think you may have been right, but after doing that I get the same dialog. I did find out that my version of the JDK is a little out of date, so I guess there's that, at least.

Comment: Doing which? Switching to a 64-bit Java or to a 32-bit Eclipse? Did you unpack it over what was already there (don't)? Did you reuse the eclipse.ini you already had (also don't)?

Comment: I got the newest version of the 64-bit JDK. I updated eclipse.ini to reflect the new directory.

Comment: Can you post the ini file contents?

Answer (score 1):

You were correct to place `-vm` and the path on separate lines in `eclipse.ini`. The error shown in your updated screen shot indicates that you're running 64-bit Eclipse on a 32-bit JDK, which doesn't work. The bit-ness of them have to match.

Answer (score 1):

No need to open eclipse.ini, just follow the path its requesting to launch it ie....most jre folders have an added extension to the name eg. jre1.8.0_45, just cut that folder from java folder and paste in eclipse folder and delete the extension. It becomes just *jre* now launch eclipse it should work.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked perfectly.  In my case the jre7 folder was missing entirely.  However, since every JDK includes a JRE within it I copied the JRE folder from inside the JDK7 folder, pasted it into the root Java folder and then renamed it from "jre" to jre7".  After that my Eclipse started up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try one of these?

(1) just copy the jre to the directory it asked.

(2) add the jvm path to system path, which is located under control panel -> system -> advanced -> environment variables.

Comment: (1) I get 
Failed to load the JNI shared library "eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"

Comment: And for 2 I need more information as to what that is and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot this is Windows... quotes. I think you need to put it in quotes because there are spaces in the string. `-vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\javaw.exe"`

Comment: With the quotes, I get the same error as before, without them I get the dialog box that I updated to my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "Program Files(x86)" in the path try using something like
C:\Progra~2\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe - for 32 Bit
C:\Progra~1\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe - for 64 bit

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For people who have tried the above solutions, as I have, and despite ensuring the same bitness and giving the direct path etc. still failing to get it to work - here's what did it for me.

-vm
java\bin

I pointed to the bin folder and Eclipse found the file it wanted (whatever it was) automatically, so try that out.

Note: I put my jre in my Eclipse folder so the path is that short for me... basically, just try pointing to the bin folder instead of a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Run java.exe from C:Prgram Files...\bin. A cmd promt will be running. Just minimize it and then try running eclipse.exe. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. I found that due to installation of JDK, I removed the path "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" in the PATH environment variable that caused the problem. SO I added this path again and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to work around this .

Recommended way : In your eclipse.ini file make sure you are pointing -vm to your jdk installation. More on this here .
Pass in the vm flag from command line. http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM

Note : Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by changing the version of jre version in the file: `Eclipse.ini` (Path: `C:\Users\"your_system_name"\eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse`)

1. In the `Eclipse.ini` file you should be able to see the line (`-vm
   C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin`) change the path to new version (`-vm
   C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin`).
2. Save & Launch the Eclipse.

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue to day.  Java updated to jre1.8.0_171 earlier this morning. There is not a VM line in the eclipse.ini file at all so the typical answer did not work. Was running from shortcut created several weeks ago. Deleted shortcut for Eclipse (Oxygen) and created new shortcut that pointed directly to the the executable and problem went away.  Cannot explain why this solution worked but it did.

Answer (score 0):

1. open - >

C:\Users\userName\eclipse\jee-2020-03\eclipse - eclipse.ini

2. find javaw.exe -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin

if Javaw.exe is present (2) in the given Path then copy the path like

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\javaw.exe

paste inside eclipse.ini after just after -vm

example:

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\javaw.exe
```

then open eclips.exe

Answer (score -1):

For this error, I struggled a lot and found this solution which will work definitely and it's very easy way.

[image]

this is the error I got. If you notice, there is path which it is unable to find, which is JDK/jre folder. So just copy "jre" folder in JDK and paste it inside "eclipse" folder, as below:

[image]

Try Restarting eclipse, it will start. Thanks!!!

Comment: Copy and pasting the Java folder isn't really a suitable solution. It needs to be changed in the PATH setting of the computer. This could cause issues later on if you are not careful

Comment: Thanks @Draken but for now its working fine !! I have set PATH in environment variables too but its not working :(